# Is there any method to store specific numeric values based on a chosen value from a look up field in MS access

Tags: database, ms-access

I'm building a database contains a "device" table, this table contains a field named "Function" and it is a text look up field where in the user can select a certain function from the drop down list, Can I store a numeric value in the database based on a certain chosen value from the list.
For example, if I chose the first item in the drop down list can I store '00' in the database?

Comment: Yes.  Investigate the following properties of the Combobox control:  RowSource, BoundColumn, ColumnCount, ColumnWidths.  The big idea is that the query contains both a column to display in the list and a *corresponding* column to store in the bound field.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.combobox

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked!